# Extract price of a relevant product on webpage

Tags: php, dom, xpath, text-extraction

I am working on a web scraper. I have searched the product title on a webpage with my product.if same product exist on the page then i want to extract the price of that product.
for this i am using XPath

here is my html code from which i need to extract price.

```
<div class="products_list_table">
    <table id="products_list_table_table" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="0" border="0">
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td valign="top" align="center">
              <span class="product_title">Malik Candy FC Composite Hockey Stick</span>
              <div class="list_price_bar all-cnrs">
                  <span class="list_price_title">Price Now:</span>
                  <span class="list_sale_price">£40.00</span>
              </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
           <td valign="top" align="center">
              <span class="product_title">Malik TC Stylish Hockey Stick</span>
              <div class="list_price_bar all-cnrs">
                  <span class="list_price_title">Price Now:</span>
                  <span class="list_sale_price">£70.00</span>
              </div>
            </td>
         </tr>

        ...
       </tbody>
     </table>
   <div>
```

There are many tr tags for all products and i search for a product title if it found i want to extract price of that product.

here is my php code in file test.php

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title']!= ''){ 
   $product_title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
   $url = 'http://www.example.com';
   $html = file_get_contents($url);     
   $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
   @$doc->loadHTML($html);      
   $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
   $found = $xpath->evaluate("boolean(//span[contains(text(), '". $product_title  ."' )])");
if($found == false){
     echo "Not Found";      
}
else { 
     $elements = $xpath->evaluate("//span[@class='list_sale_price']");
     if (!is_null($elements)) {
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
             $nodes = $element->childNodes;
             foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                 echo $node->nodeValue.'<br>';
                 }
        }
     }
}
 }

?>
```

here i am using form in test.php to search product

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="" method="post">
       <label>Enter product title to search</label><br /><br />
       <input type="text" name="title" size="50" /><br /><br />
       <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="msg()"/>
   </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

After finding the product, i want to extract price of that product but the it displays all the prices on the page. where i made mistake. Need xpath expression to extract the price of matched product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple expressions. You can extract the price with *one* XPath expression by selecting the `div` following your matched `span`, and in this context, extracting its child `span` which has the class of `list_sale_price`:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Malik Candy' )]/following-sibling::div/span[@class='list_sale_price']
```

Comment: Thanks helderdarocha can you please tell me how to display that price because it could not display in foreach code that i have written for displaying?